# Inductance and Mutual inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, inductance

Question: Three coils with inductances $L_1, L_2$ and $L_3$, as well as mutual inductances $M_{12}, M_{13}$ and $M_{23}$ are connected in series. What is the total inductance?

The right answer is $L_1+L_2+L_3+2(M_{12}+M_{13}$ +$M_{23})$.
I don't understand why there is a factor $2$ for the mutual inductance. I use Physics handbook for science and engineering and I could not find anything about the total mutual inductance in series..

Comment: As a hint: L2 has the same mutual inductance effect on the voltage across L1 as L1 has on the voltage across L2.